# Sqlite problem?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ipad

someone is using .sqlite file, someone is using .sql file, someone is using .rdb file...Which one is the best among this one? is there differences among them?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference - it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: of taste (just a misprint) ))